# F(x)*F(-x) way to separate?

Tags: matlab, function

I have this problem:

```
|K(jw)/H(jw)|^2 = |1-G(jw)|^2/|1+G(jw)|^2
```

By using something called analytical continuation (just following the book here), we get:

```
[K(s)K(-s)]/[H(s)H(-s)] = [(1-G(s))(1-G(-s))]/[(1+G(s))(1+G(-s))]
```

So then we can identify:

```
K(s)/H(s) = (1-G(s))/(1+G(s))
```

Is there a elegant way of doing this? Been on this for a while and couldn't think of one.

Comment: Im confused, you are talking abou tmaths, but doing it in MATLAB? those maths are done in paper, what are you doing in MATLAB?

Comment: you should ask this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I need to achieve this using code. That is, I will input G(jw) or G(s)*G(-s) (not expressed in its factors G(s) and G(-s), but a single transfer function) and find K(s)/H(s). Not by hand.

Comment: If you are inputting some combined function `G(s)*G(-s)` then there is no general way to extract `G(s)` and `G(-s)` without more information. You need to work out what you want to achieve and *how* before you try and put it into code, Matlab (or any other language) can't guess what you're trying to do and magically give you a solution! I don't think your simplification is even necessarily correct, what book are you following? Give us more justification. Asking on math.stack may help you understand what you're actually doing!